# Stop recyclerview scrolling when loading- Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

When the RecyclerView Reaches the end it will load another pair of data

but while loading RecyclerView, the *empty view of RecyclerView is visible* and if the empty view is clicked it gives me *ArrayBoundaryExeption*

so i need to stop scrolling when it isLoading

[image: There is Empty View in RecyclerView So need to Stop Scrolling.]

```
       mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycleView);     
       mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
       mUserAdapter = new UserAdapter();
       mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mUserAdapter);


     mUserAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore() {

        /*    mRecyclerView.stopNestedScroll();
            mRecyclerView.stopScroll();
            CustomGridLayoutManager ss= new CustomGridLayoutManager(WorkNow.this);
            ss.setScrollEnabled(false);
            mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
            linearLayoutManager.canScrollVertically();  */

            //   if (Choose.equals("Local")) {
            Log.e("haint", "Load More");
            mUsers.add(null);
            mUserAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mUsers.size() - 1);
            dataLoadMore();
            //mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
          //  mRecyclerView.stopScroll();

            //Load more data for reyclerview
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                  /*  mRecyclerView.stopNestedScroll();
                    mRecyclerView.stopScroll();
                    CustomGridLayoutManager ss= new CustomGridLayoutManager(WorkNow.this);
                    ss.setScrollEnabled(false);
                    mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
                    linearLayoutManager.canScrollVertically();  */

                    Log.e("haint", "Load More 2");
                   // mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
                 //   mRecyclerView.stopScroll();

                    //Remove loading item
                    if (!mUsers.isEmpty()) {
                        mUsers.remove(mUsers.size() - 1);
                        mUserAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(mUsers.size());
                    }


                        for (int i = 0; i < lenMore; i++) {
                            LocalListView localListView = new LocalListView();


                            localListView.setJob_local_id(job_local_idM[i]);
                            localListView.setJob_typess(job_typessM[i]);

                            mUsers.add(localListView);
                        }
                    mUserAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    mUserAdapter.setLoaded();
                }
            }, 5000);
        }

    });


     RecycleClick.addTo(mRecyclerView).setOnItemClickListener(new RecycleClick.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
            // YOUR CODE

            if(mUserAdapter.isLoading){
                    //
             /*     mRecyclerView.stopNestedScroll();
                   mRecyclerView.stopScroll();
                  CustomGridLayoutManager ss= new 
                 CustomGridLayoutManager(WorkNow.this);
                  ss.setScrollEnabled(false);
                 mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
                 linearLayoutManager.canScrollVertically();  */
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Loading please 
                 wait...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }else if(position!=-1){

                    Intent is = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WorkProfileLocal.class);
                    is.putExtra("job_local_idG", mUsers.get(position).getJob_local_id());
                    is.putExtra("user_idsG", mUsers.get(position).getUser_ids());

                    startActivity(is);

            }
        }
    });



    static class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    public TextView tvJobTitle;
    public TextView tvJobWork;

       public UserViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvHirerName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvWhatWork);
        tvJobTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvJobTitle);

    }
}

static class LoadingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ProgressBar progressBar;


    public LoadingViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);


    }
}

class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private final int VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private final int VIEW_TYPE_LOADING = 1;

    private OnLoadMoreListener mOnLoadMoreListener;

    private boolean isLoading;
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;

    public UserAdapter() {
        final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
        mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

                if (!isLoading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                    if (mOnLoadMoreListener != null) {
                        mOnLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();

                      /*  mRecyclerView.stopNestedScroll();
                        mRecyclerView.stopScroll();
                        CustomGridLayoutManager ss= new CustomGridLayoutManager(WorkNow.this);
                        ss.setScrollEnabled(false);
                        mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
                        linearLayoutManager.canScrollVertically();*/
                    }
                    isLoading = true;
                  /*  mRecyclerView.stopNestedScroll();
                    mRecyclerView.stopScroll();
                    CustomGridLayoutManager ss= new CustomGridLayoutManager(WorkNow.this);
                    ss.setScrollEnabled(false);
                    mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
                    linearLayoutManager.canScrollVertically(); */

                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener mOnLoadMoreListener) {
        this.mOnLoadMoreListener = mOnLoadMoreListener;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mUsers.get(position) == null ? VIEW_TYPE_LOADING : VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(WorkNow.this).inflate(R.layout.list_view_local_jobs, parent, false);
            return new UserViewHolder(view);
        } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_LOADING) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(WorkNow.this).inflate(R.layout.layout_loading_item, parent, false);
           /* mRecyclerView.stopNestedScroll();
            mRecyclerView.stopScroll();
            CustomGridLayoutManager ss= new CustomGridLayoutManager(WorkNow.this);
            ss.setScrollEnabled(false);
            mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
            linearLayoutManager.canScrollVertically(); */
            return new LoadingViewHolder(view);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder instanceof UserViewHolder) {
            LocalListView localListView = mUsers.get(position);
            UserViewHolder userViewHolder = (UserViewHolder) holder;
            userViewHolder.tvHirerName.setText(localListView.getUser_names());
            userViewHolder.tvJobTitle.setText(localListView.getJob_titles().replaceAll("_", " "));


            if (localListView.getImage().isEmpty()) {
                userViewHolder.hirerPicLocal.setImageResource(R.drawable.blank_low);
            } else{
                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .load(localListView.getImage())
                        .into(userViewHolder.hirerPicLocal);
            }



        } else if (holder instanceof LoadingViewHolder) {
            LoadingViewHolder loadingViewHolder = (LoadingViewHolder) holder;
            loadingViewHolder.progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

         /*   mRecyclerView.stopNestedScroll();
            mRecyclerView.stopScroll();
            CustomGridLayoutManager ss= new CustomGridLayoutManager(WorkNow.this);
            ss.setScrollEnabled(false);
            mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
            linearLayoutManager.canScrollVertically(); */

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUsers == null ? 0 : mUsers.size();
    }

    public void setLoaded() {
        isLoading = false;
    }
}
```

This Class i got from StackOverFlow to StopScroll But it is not working.

```
public class CustomGridLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
    private boolean isScrollEnabled = true;


    public CustomGridLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setScrollEnabled(boolean flag) {
        this.isScrollEnabled = flag;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canScrollVertically() {
        //Similarly you can customize "canScrollHorizontally()" for managing horizontal scroll
        return isScrollEnabled && super.canScrollVertically();
    }
}
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(WorkNow.this) {
    @Override
    public boolean canScrollVertically() {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Show error log pls. I think your click on loading view might go to `else if(position!=-1)` and there you got outOfBounds. 
If that's problem then create recyclerview callbacks manualy by creating listener and passing it to adapter. Item clicks will call method of listener and loading view will not call it. I think it is more clean than using "set click on all views in adapter"

Comment: `else if(position!=-1)` this will prevent from `ArrayBoundaryExeption` 
But `if(mUserAdapter.isLoading)` is preventing from clicking
I want to Click without `ArrayBoundaryExeption`

Comment: @JanuszHain i want to _stopScrolling when it is Loading_.  So That i dont get that emptyView shown in Image

Comment: have u tried `! mUserAdapter.isLoading`? "Not" is loading will work in this case, but as I said, using "click on all views listener" is not really clean way even if it will work

Comment: are u talking about empty view or loading item (with progress bar)?

Comment: Yea i want to keep the loading progress bar in bottom.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154052/discussion-between-iamraja-and-janusz-hain).